# Laravel: is it possible to apply a ->where() over a hasMany()?

Tags: php, laravel, orm

I have this `notifications` table, where it has a `status` column. The status might be, among other things, "ack" and "noack". So, the notifications belongs to a user. If I want to use the ORM to see the user's notifications I'd use a `hasMany()` in the User model like:

```
public function notificaciones()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Notification', 'dest_id', 'id');
}
```

And this works perfectly. (The dest_id means who the notification is for, there's another origin_id which tells who caused the Notification, any ways, this works)

Now, I want to see only the unacknoledged (noack) notifications, I was thinking on:

```
public function notificaciones()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Notificacion', 'dest_id', 'id')
                  ->where('status', 'noack');
}
```

But this produces an empty collection.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: There's no reason that this code would not work. Is this the entire code and how is this used in practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like that,

You create a new function in the same model and call that core method with the condition to fetch `noack` notifications.

```
public function noack_notifications() {
    return $this->notificaciones()->where('status','=', 'noack');
}
```

When you call this method from controller with find.

```
$user =  User::find($id);
dd($user->noack_notifications()->get());
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: This function will return the query, should he include `->get()` at the end for getting the item collection?

Comment: Yes in User model and I updated my answer. Once check now @namelivia